# Django: CONN_MAX_AGE persists connections, with gthread worker class of gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn, database-connection

I am using Django, without `MAX_CONN_AGE` setting (default = 0), this leads to creation of connection in each request, and connection is not reused in django ORM.

This is causing multiple postgres connect as my api is getting called multiple times, I want to achieve something like connection pooling or singleton connection so that connection is reused.

I am using `gunicorn -k gthread --threads 2 --workers 4`.

so,

1. does `MAX_CONN_AGE` works fine with gthread? connection will be reused and closed properly? Can you explain the working.
2. And what would be the behaviour of `MAX_CONN_AGE` with gevent worker class?